# Python urllib2 response 404 error but url can be opened

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-404, urllib2, python-requests

I came across a situation when I used Python Requests or urllib2 to open urls. I got 404 'page not found' responses. For example, url = 'https://www.facebook.com/mojombo'. However, I can copy and paste those urls in browser and visit them. Why does this happen?

I need to get some content from those pages' html source code. Since I can't open those urls using Requests or urllib2, I can't use BeautifulSoup to extract element from html source code. Is there a way to get those page's source code and extract content form it utilizing Python?

Although this is a general question, I still need some working code to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely, you need to be logged into Facebook to view the page. I'm not logged in, and I also get 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your browser is using cookies to log you in.  Try opening that url in a private or incognito tab, and you'll probably not be able to access it.
**However**, if you are using Requests, you can pass the appropriate login information as a dictionary of values.  You'll need to check the form information to see what the fields are, but Requests can handle that as well.
The normal format would be:

```
payload = {
   'username': 'your username',
   'password': 'your password'
   }
p = requests.post(myurl, data=payload)
```

with more or less fields added as needed.